# Action class not accepting selenium driver as variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, action

I'm looking to scroll a webpage to view in selenium.
The example codes I got from online are as follows:

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.id("element-id"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.MoveToElement(element);
actions.Perform();
```

Yet when i utilize it this way:

```
IWebElement element = driverFF.FindElement(By.Id("qr_reply"));

Action actions = new Action(driverFF);
actions.MoveToElement(element);
actions.Perform();
```

I get thrown a "Method name expected." error at the second line.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you are using wrong class, As you see in the example code it should be [`Actions`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Interactions_Actions.htm) with [`OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/N_OpenQA_Selenium_Interactions.htm) Namespace instead of `Action` as below :-

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;

Actions actions = new Actions(driverFF);
actions.MoveToElement(element);
actions.Perform();
```

Comment: Hi, i added the using but was noted by the ide as an "unneeded Using".
The "Actions" keyword could not be found as well.

Comment: @user4985 sorry it should be `using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions`...try with updated answer...:)

Answer (score 0):

Action is an interface : public interface Action. Action Interface represents a single user-interaction action. and Actions is a Class

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).